# How to intercept and validate header value for all incoming requests in spring cloud gateway?

Tags: spring-cloud-gateway

config file for the application is:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    gateway:
      routes:
        - id: gateway-server
          uri: http://localhost:8081
          predicates:
            - Path=/**
          filters:
            - SomeFilterFactory
```

Filter used is:

```
public class SomeFilterFactory
        extends AbstractGatewayFilterFactory<SomeFilterFactory.SomeConfig> {


    public SomeFilterFactory() {
        super(SomeFilterFactory.SomeConfig.class);
    }

    @Override
    public GatewayFilter apply(SomeFilterFactory.SomeConfig config) {

        return (exchange, chain) -> {
            ServerHttpRequest request = exchange.getRequest();
            String someHeader = request.getHeaders().getFirst("someHeader");
            // do your things here
            return chain.filter(exchange);
        };
    }

    public static class SomeConfig {
        // your config if required
        // or use name value config
    }
```

My requirement is to validate header value passed in every incoming request before passed downstream.

Answer (score -1):

You have to set your filter name end with "GatewayFilterFactory". And in config file you have to set filter with normalized FilterFactory Name.

In below link, you can check what normalized FilterFactory name is.
https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-gateway/blob/4bd159895bd45193905d652d39a7542c35a5163c/spring-cloud-gateway-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/gateway/support/NameUtils.java#L46-L50

If your filter name is `SomeGatewayFilterFactory`, normalized name is `Some`.

And your config file will be like below example.

```
spring:
  cloud:
    gateway:
      routes:
        - id: gateway-server
          uri: http://localhost:8081
          predicates:
            - Path=/**
          filters:
            - name: Some
              args:
                KEY1: VALUE1
                KEY2: VALUE2
```

Replace KEY and VALUE with your `SomeConfig` properties.

Comment: Did not work, not able to intercept the header passed in request

Comment: I changed yml file, `Something` -> `Some` filter name. Could you show your yml and FilterFactory code?